# How to check pep8 standards in my code

Tags: python

i am developing a python library with couple of modules and files. I have read through the pep8 rules given in the below link

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Is there any package or software available which can check the python styles and structure .

for example , indendation with spaces or tabs , variable conventions etc.

I am looking for a module which can perform this task..

Comment: There is a tool for this; it's called pep8. `pip install pep8` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Comment: PyCharm can check this as you develop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term for this is "linting". A Python module called [Pylint](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint) is available.

It checks for coding standards and errors with full customizability. It can be run from the command line, as part of a continuous integration workflow, integrated into various IDEs.

On Debian and many derivatives, it can be installed with `apt install pylint`. Use the module like this:

```
python3 -m pylint your_file.py
```

Comment: Answering an off-topic question merely encourages the asker and future readers to post more off-topic questions.

Comment: Saying this is "off topic" seems a little subjective. Tooling is an important aspect of programming. All the "tools" mentioned are python modules that can be imported and used in a variety of workflows.

Comment: oops.. Sorry about it.. Is there any way i can delete or close this question. will do it from my end immediately !!!

Comment: As I remember it, the off-topic reason says "book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource".  I don't see why a third-party module wouldn't fit into that.

Comment: Fair enough, though I feel like if the question were re-worded then the answer about linting would still be worth keeping.

Comment: It this answer up to date (2021)?